# Двоичное представление числа, почему так

Tags: c++, binary

```
int DecimalToBinary (int number){
    int binary = 0, remainder = 0, i = 1;
 
    while (number != 0){
         remainder = number % 2;
         number /= 2;
         binary += remainder * i;
         i *= 10;
      }
    
    return binary;
 
}
```

Есть такая функция, она переводит числа из десятичной в двоичную систему счисления.
С первыми двумя строками цикла while все вроде бы ясно, но потом, я не понимаю зачем мы **binary += remainder * i**, и зачем i *= 10.

Объясните пожалуйста, почему все именно так.

Comment: remainder получает значеие 0 или 1, затем умножается на 1, 10, 100, 1000 и т.д.  (i *= 10)

Comment: ну и это не совсем перевод в двоичную систему, скорее это перевод в десятичную, в которой десятичное число выглядит как двоичное

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, спасибо, но зачем оно умножается потом? (i *= 10)

Comment: а это такое добавление в конец числе ещё одной цифры. помедитируйте над этим

Comment: Чтобы на каждом следующем шаге `i` было в 10 раз больше, соответствнно `reminder` при умножении на `i` становился десятками, сотнями, тысячами и т.д. перед сложением с конечным результатом.

Comment: спасибо за ответы!